# How to slide bodyB over bodyA without affecting bodyA's movement in Box2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to achieve a *burning matchstick effect* on table. So its top down view with zero gravity. Wherever the matchstick goes it's attached fire should follow linearly. So I believe prismatic joints is what I need.

My matchstick is a rectangle and my fire is a sensor circle.

I went through this [tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-prismatic) on prismatic joint. At one place it says "Setting the bodies to the same translation values 'Clamps' bodies together". But when I tried this, `bodyB` doesn't slide.

1. `prismaticJoint->setLimit(transVal,transVal);`
2. Although this one works:
     `prismaticJoint->setLimit(transVal,transVal+0.1);`

(where `transVal` is well within limits.)

In method 1, when I print `prismaticJoint->getJointTranslation`, it always shows `0.000` (or `-0.000`).

In method 2, `bodyB` does slide and the translation values are correct But then my `bodyA` also starts moving in the opposite direction to the `localAxisA` as if `bodyA` is being pushed back because of the slide.

I want my matchstick not to be affected by the linear movement of the joint. My Fire should stay impervious to any bumps caused by other objects on the table.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 'clamped together' means they don't slide, because they act as if they are stuck/fixed/welded together. How about if you change the value of transVal gradually, and do setLimit every timeStep? You can make the flame sensor fixture very light (low density) so that its movement does not affect the match.

Comment: Thanks,that does work,but what if my matchstick is edge shaped instead of rectangle?Edge shapes don't have much inhernt mass,i suppose and because of that the same behaviour is shown.I do have that kind of scenario too.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to add a fixture that does have mass (eg. polygon or circle) to the body to give it some mass. You can set the collision mask bits of this extra fixture so it doesn't play a part in any collisions. So the body would have some mass, but only the edge would be used to collide with other things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and your tutorials are awesome btw. :)